# Is there any way to force a Connector synchronization of an object via SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

I couldn't find anywhere in the API documentation, but is there a way to, via SSJS, force an entity synchronization on an object (Connector)?  The issue I'm running into is I created an automation that runs a SSJS activity that updates a certain field on a certain object in Service Cloud.  Then, I would need to put a wait step in the automation (to wait for the 15 minute sync window to happen), and then execute the audience query/email send.  What I would like to have happen is to be 100% certain that the data from Service Cloud sync'd over to Marketing Cloud before I run any other activities that depend on that data being there, and if the "Refresh" icon in Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronized has the ability to be programmatically invoked via API, that would be amazing.

Comment: there is no way to change/force the sync schedule

Comment: @EazyE you're talking via API, right?  Because we can certainly force a sync by clicking the refresh icon.

Comment: Correct, but if you have the information in the marketing cloud already, why are you updating SFDC then waiting for it to sync back, why don't you just the data that you already have?